# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error API PUT : Update method doesn't work [Spring-boot]

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, api, rest, put

I want to update user but it doesn't work for other models it's simply working, whereas user no so can someone help me to find the solution. By the way I'm using spring-boot and mongodb.

```
 public void changeUserPassword(Utilisateur user, String password) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
        utilisateurRepository.save(user);
    }

@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@Valid @RequestBody Utilisateur user, @PathVariable String id){

       Optional<Utilisateur> userData = utilisateurRepository.findById(id);

       if(userData.isPresent()) {
           user.setId_user(id);
           this.changeUserPassword(user, user.getNewpassword());
           this.utilisateurRepository.save(user);
           return new ResponseEntity<>("User successfully updated", HttpStatus.OK);
       }
       else {
           return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
       }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share more details like , stacktrace if your code is throwing an exception or probably try to debug and find which code is causing the issue for you.

Comment: I solve the issue I removed the @NotBlank that I put in model so thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What causing the issue is in the model I added @NotBlank for variable so I remove it and thats work perfectly